# Keras: Model Compilation Giving "Index 200005 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 200000" Error

Tags: machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I'm using Jena Climate Data that my book gives a link to. I have it below;
https://s3.amazonaws.com/keras-datasets/jena_climate_2009_2016.csv.zip

---

I tried messing with it but I have no clue why the index is surpassing 200000. I'm not sure why it gets to 200005 since my training data is 200001 observations long.

I've also gotten an error that said, " Index 200000 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 200000."

The data is 420551x14 of weather data. My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import keras

data = pd.read_csv("D:\\School\\Spring_2019\\GraduateProject\\jena_climate_2009_2016_Data\\jena_climate_2009_2016.csv")
data = data.iloc[:,data.columns!='Date Time']
data

# Standardize the Data
from sklearn import preprocessing
data = preprocessing.scale(data[:200000])

# Build Generators
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
target = data[:,1] # Should target be scaled?
# ? Do I need to remove targets from the data variable?
trainGen = TimeseriesGenerator(data,targets=target,length=1440,
                               sampling_rate=6,
                               batch_size=190,
                               start_index=0,
                               end_index=200000)
valGen = TimeseriesGenerator(data,targets=target,length=1440,
                             sampling_rate=6,
                             batch_size=190,
                               start_index=199999,
                               end_index=300000)
testGen = TimeseriesGenerator(data,targets=target,length=6,
                              batch_size=128,
                             start_index=300000,
                             end_index=420550)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import layers
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras.layers import LSTM

#Flatten part is: 240 = lookback//step. This is 1440/6 because we are looking at 
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Flatten(input_shape=(240,data.shape[-1])))
model.add(layers.Dense(32,activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))

val_steps = 300000-200001-1440
model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(),loss='mae')
history = model.fit_generator(trainGen,
                             steps_per_epoch=250,
                             epochs=20,
                             validation_data=valGen,
                             validation_steps=val_steps)
```

Let me know if you need anything else and thank you greatly in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've only selected first 200000 rows for your data (data = preprocessing.scale(data[:200000]), so validation and test generators are out of bounds (index > 200000)